# How to write separate values of the array from one column

Tags: arrays, .net, csv, c#-2.0

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string[] LinesInFile = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\Book.csv");

        foreach (string line in LinesInFile)
        {
            if (line != "")
            {
                string[] columns = line.Split(',');
                string PatientID = columns[0];
                string DateOfBirth = columns[1];
                string DateFirstSeen = columns[2];
                string DateOfDiagnosis = columns[3];
                string TreatmentStartDate = columns[4];
                string TreatmentEndDate = columns[5];
                string CancerType = columns[6];
                string TreatmentType = columns[7];

                Console.WriteLine(PatientID[0]);
            }
        }
}
```

This is some of the data from the csv file,

```
1,30/07/1966,06/01/2017,21/01/2017,01/02/2017,01/06/2018,4,3
2,25/09/1970,02/01/2017,27/01/2017,04/02/2017,06/05/2018,5,1
3,23/08/1964,11/01/2017,19/01/2017,04/02/2017,31/03/2018,5,1
```

So basically when I print 'PatientID' it will print them all from 1-3 I want it so I can print each individually so if i only wanted to print the first row I can. I was thinking of using a list to save each 'patients' information but even then how would I return each patients information individually if I needed to compare information.

Comment: Create a class containing patient information while parsing your csv file save each row entry as an instance of Patient class and then add that instance to a list of patients variable which you can use to retrieve individual patient information per your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class of the book with all the atributtes that you need like PatientID ,DateOfBirth , DateFirstSeen etc and then create a list of that class (List< newclass >) so you can store the data in the list by line.

Answer (score 0):

Should be some help :

```
public class Patient {
    public string PatientID {get; set;}
    public string DateOfBirth {get; set;}
    public string DateFirstSeen {get; set;}
    public string DateOfDiagnosis {get; set;}
    public string TreatmentStartDate {get; set;}
    public string TreatmentEndDate {get; set;}
    public string CancerType {get; set;}
    public string TreatmentType {get; set;}
}
List<Patient> lstPatients = new List<Patient>();
lstPatients.add(new Patient{PatientID = columns[0],DateOfBirth = columns[1],..v.v});
```

Comment: That will give compile time error *Patient does not contain a constructor that takes x arguments*. Update your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class of patient to store each Patient information. And store all patients in a list. Then you can retrieve it from the list:

```
        public class Patient
        {
            public string PatientID;
            public string DateOfBirth;
            public string DateFirstSeen;
            public string DateOfDiagnosis;
            public string TreatmentStartDate;
            public string TreatmentEndDate;
            public string CancerType;
            public string TreatmentType;
        }

        public static List<Patient> LoadPatients(string filePath)
        {
            var list = new List<Patient>();
            string[] LinesInFile = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\Book.csv");

            foreach (string line in LinesInFile)
            {
                if (line != "")
                {

                    string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                    list.Add(new Patient
                    {
                        PatientID = columns[0],
                        DateOfBirth =columns[1],
                        DateFirstSeen = columns[2],
                        DateOfDiagnosis = columns[3],
                        TreatmentStartDate = columns[4],
                        TreatmentEndDate = columns[5],
                        CancerType = columns[6],
                        TreatmentType = columns[7]
                    });
                }
            }

            return list;
        }

        public static Patient GetPatient(List<Patient> patients, string patientId)
        {
            return patients.FirstOrDefault(pt => pt.PatientID.Equals(patientId));
        }


        #endregion
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var patients = LoadPatients("D:\\Book.csv");
            var patient = GetPatient(patients, "2");
        }
```

Comment: How woud I print different patients information in rows, I tried to print 'patient' but it just returns the projectname and some other useless information.